# php mail script is not sending email

Tags: php

I have this code!

```
$to = "xyz@gmail.com";
$subject = "Order Confirmation - Your Order with Mysite.com[] has been successfully placed!";
$from = " abc@gmail.com.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane !</h1>';
$message .= '<table>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<th>Order Detail</th>';
$message .= '<th>Delivery Address</th>';
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td>Order successfully placed.We are pleased to confirm your order no OD111288994161211000.Thank you for shopping with Mywebsite!</td>';
$message .= '<td>xyz</td>';
$message .= '</tr></table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Its not sending mail. Is there any problem with syntax.

Comment: Perhaps you should entertain the posibility that the email is send but not received? Solution: Try a normal mailbox, not GMail or HotMail and the like, preferably a mailbox on a server you control.

Comment: Why to use like this `with Mysite.com[]`